# Passing a ref or pointer to a managed type as an argument in C++.net

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I'm really baffled by this - I know how to do this in VB, unmanaged C++ and C# but for some reason I can't accept a ref variable of a managed type in C++. I'm sure there's a simple answer, really - but here's the C# equivalent:

```
myClass.myFunction(ref variableChangedByfunction);
```

I've tried C++ pointers - no dice. I've tried ref keywords. No dice. I tried the `[out]` keyword. Didn't work.

I can't find any documentation that clearly explains my problem, either.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out in the function declaration you need to use a % after the parameter name:

bool Importer::GetBodyChunk(String^% BodyText, String^% ChunkText)

And then you pass in the variable per usual.

Answer (score 2):

Use a ^ instead of a *

Comment: I used a ^ - it doesn't appear to pass a reference though. If I modify the contents of the variable they're not reflected in the variable I passed in (according to my watch window at least.)

Comment: ...Oh man. You mean on the variable I'm passing in.

I never even thought to do that despite being well aware of that operator. Lemme try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it a little clearer:

Parameters of reference types (e.g. System::String) have to be denoted with `^` in the newer C++/CLI syntax. This tells the compiler that the parameter is a handle to a GC object.

If you need a tracking reference (like with `ref` or `out` in C#) you need to add `%` as well.

And here comes a tip: I often find it helpful to use the [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to look at existing assemblies and switch to C++ code style. This gives good insight into usage of attributes for interoperability between different .net languages.